# backing up Huge amount of data on a slow drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, encryption, 7-zip

I have this new and cheap Seagate Archive drive,without hardware encryption ability. It have 8TB of space. Transfer in real time seams to reach a rate as slow as 15MB/S

This drive is still can serves its main purpose: namely storing data securely for some time.

I have also another identical drive just to backup, again, the first drive.
The problem is that i am using the encryption software VeraCrypt,that is based on TrueCrypt. That software seams to be the best option now, for the fact that it encrypt almost any amount of data to a file that can be mounted as a drive almost without any loss of performance of the disk it resides on.

However, i am more careful about the health of the drive than its performance. My purpose purely is security; backing up and encryption.

The problem is that with the rate of transfer reaching 16MB/S at worst, saving a file (that is an encrypted container) could takes no less than two day. But i cannot leave the machine up for that long because of my situation now.

Should i try just to make smaller containers(of 100Gb) in my Laptop, fill them with data and then send them to the drive as they are then treated just as files?
Should i consider other softwares like 7zip and its encryption that enable splitting into parts? bad that would lead to very much extra work.

Update 1:
-I found some alternatives, Ultracopier, available in Ubuntu, that software can be used to copy a file for say 10 hours, and i have to move, i just pause the transfer and continue another time. I have never encountered a similar function.

Comment: 15mg/s -- Do you mean 15MB/s or 15Mb/s? Milligrams/second doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I am sorry : 15mb/s

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am understanding you correctly but, I use some commercial software [AJC Sync](http://www.ajcsoft.com/file-sync-editions.php) (one of the few packages I have purchased other than Office and a VLE) to compare and back up files. Since it compares and only copies accross the files that have been added and changed it is quick. I use the standard edition at 29 USD but the professional edition at 35 USD has the option to encrypt.

There are [other similar packages including freeware](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/the-15-best-file-syncing-apps-on-the-planet-537704).

Comment: the files are to be saved locally , no Internet or synchronization  is needed. Also i am using Linux exclusively. My only problem is that i cannot wait so long for a slow drive to save a very big file (encrypted container) because of my circumstances.

Comment: I use AJC locally but sorry yes, it is only for windows. I recommended synchronisation because backup speed increase exponentially since one only saves new content. There are linux programs such as http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/
but if you generate a large volume of content, then my suggestion is useless, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, 15MB/second is really really slow for any hard drives (at least from this millennium I think), it's more like a USB flash drive speed - are you writing to a USB flash drive? If so, then that's just it's "speed limit" you're stuck with. Or maybe you're using a USB drive that for some reason is limited in speed - does changing it's USB hub/cable/port make it any faster? Or is it faster on another computer? Maybe there's a problem to be solved there.

If I understand correctly, you're:

1. using big 100GB files as containers for VeraCrypt, each container holding a fixed-size filesystem with your backup files (daily / weekly backups?).
2. copying the big 100GB files somewhere else for a secondary backup (weekly / monthly backups?).

If you changed your backup strategy to only copy the files *inside* the big 100GB containers (after mounting the to & from containers) that would let you use programs like **`rsync`** to copy a bunch of smaller files, stop & continue copying later where you left off. Also, you could/should be using incremental backups, tracking & copying only the files that have changed since the last full backup, so instead of copying 100GB every day, maybe only a few small config files change each day, maybe even a few KB or MB (plus downloads, if you even need backups of those).

If only a few small parts of your 100GB files are changed, then using **`rsync`** and the **`--no-whole-file`** option may only copy the changed sections, instead of 100GB's to write - but it **still needs to read both files** to find the changed parts, and at 15MB/second it may be no faster (if you're using *flash* storage media, then less writes = longer life, so may be worth it).

There are lots of backup programs to choose from, see a few questions like these, most should support **incremental backups** to only copy changed files:

- [Comparison of backup tools - askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

Or you can write one yourself (like I did) that keeps an index of what files have been backed up & their hashes/times, and on the next run compares the files to their hashes/times to only copy new & changed files. **Bash** works great with **`find`**, **`cksum`** or the secure but much slower **`shaXsum`** programs, **`diff`** the list of files & hashes to find & copy new/changed files. And to be extra secure you could even backup files to **gpg-encrypted** **tar-compressed** archives that take up the same or less space than the original files, not 100GB's at a time.

Also, since you're exclusively using Linux, why not use LUKS / cryptsetup for your encryption? It's "been around the block" for a few years & *in theory* should be more stable than a relatively new program like VeraCrypt.